# Why index increase execution time in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, postgresql-9.1

I have created index on `'workflow.status'` field but why after index creation query execution time is increased?

**Query:**

```
select workflow.* from 
    ( 
        SELECT  CASE 
    WHEN cert.value = 'true' THEN 0 
    ELSE 1 END lawAndOrder, workflow.*  
    FROM testdb.statuschanges hist, testdb.usercerts cert, testdb.workflow 
    WHERE workflow.taskid = hist.taskid AND hist.username = cert.username  AND cert.projectname = 'Core_EECA_RUS_2018_shp_UPDGeo_LL'  AND cert.key = 'DISABLECOMMIT' 
    AND hist.statuschangeid =workflow.proposedstatuschangeid AND workflow.status in ('Check')and workflow.projectname = 'Core_EECA_RUS_2018_shp_UPDGeo_LL'  AND workflow.claimedby IS NULL
    UNION 
    SELECT CASE
    WHEN workflow.status = 'INProgress' THEN 1
    WHEN workflow.status = 'Feedback' THEN 2 
    WHEN workflow.status not     in ('Check', 'INProgress', 'Feedback') THEN 3 
    END lawAndOrder,workflow.*  
    FROM testdb.workflow  
    WHERE       workflow.status != 'Check' AND       workflow.claimedby IS NULL  AND workflow.projectname = 'Core_EECA_RUS_2018_shp_UPDGeo_LL'  order by lawAndOrder ASC, TaskId
    ) 
    workflow WHERE ProjectName = 'Core_EECA_RUS_2018_shp_UPDGeo_LL'  AND
    Status IN  ('SourcedFromGuidedCommunity', 'NeedsWorkInTIF', 'NeedsFieldCollection', 'INProgress', 'Completed', 'Check', 'New', 'Reject', 'In Testing', 'Check Reject', 'Check Accept with minor remark', 'InQA', 'Rework', 'Feedback') 
    AND ClaimedBy IS NULL
```

**Index creation statement:**

```
CREATE INDEX idx_workflow_status
  ON testdb.workflow
  USING btree
  (status COLLATE pg_catalog."default");
```

Is it possible index increases time?

Comment: Yes, that is possible. Add `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for more.

Comment: While you gather the information, [this](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/index-decreases-select-performance/) may make interesting reading.

Comment: The index on `status` won't help for a query with `!=` to begin with. A better index for that query would be `create index on workflow (projectname, claimedby) where status <> 'Check'`

Comment: Unrelated, but: in the expression `FROM testdb.workflow` the identifier `testdb` refers to a schema, not a "database". Naming a schema "db" is pretty confusing

Answer (score 0):

This answer is skipping over some of the specifics, but is generally applicable.

When planning a query, Postgres will look at each *potentially* relevant index. It will then either pick what appears to be the most suitable index for the query, or will decide to use no index at all if none of the relevant indexes appear suitable at all.

If the query is already using an index and you create a less suitable index, or if the query is not using an index and you create an unsuitable index; Postgres will take longer to plan the query as it now has another index file it has to look at and compare to other potential query plans.

You can see which, if any, index is being used by a query by utilizing explain/analyze (You may find the output easier to understand if you use the visual explain/analyze built into PgAdmin).

Postgres also stores statistics for indexes (Which are very easily viewable through PgAdmin) - it is good practice to review these, and remove unused and duplicate indexes from your database.